# getting error Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query. in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new here in sql server, I am working on query, when i run the query it gives me error `Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.`, i tried all the possible scenarios, still i am not able to resolve it, here is my sql query, can anyone please point to me why i am getting this error ?

```
UPDATE [e]
    SET 
       [e].[LUPADays] = IIF((IIF(([p].[payer_type]) <> '1', 0, IIF([EpEnd] <= GETDATE(), 0, IIF([TotVisits] < 5, 1, 0)))) = 0, 0, CONVERT(datetime,EpEnd) - GETDATE())
FROM [tb_Episode] AS [e]
LEFT JOIN [tb_Payer] AS [p]
     ON([e].[CustID] = [p].[company_id])
       AND ([e].[PayorType] = [p].[payor_type])
LEFT JOIN [tb_HHPPS] AS [h]
     ON [e].[HHPPS] = [h].[HHPPS]
WHERE 
    [e].[billed_flag] = '0';
```

Comment: Presumably `EpEnd` is an int, not a date. Since you are comparing it to a date (GETDATE), you should convert it to a date (or convert `GETDATE` to an int).

Comment: @HoneyBadger thanks for your effort, EpEnd is date field, its datatype is date

Comment: It's very hard to read all those `IFF's`, but it seems one of the possible outcomes is `0`, this is definitely not a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your own query, the error appears to be that you are comparing `EpEnd` against `GETDATE()` directly, without a conversion.  You do make the appropriate conversion later in the query, so just do it earlier as well:

```
UPDATE [e]
SET 
   [e].[LUPADays] = IIF((IIF([p].[payer_type] <> '1', 0,
       IIF(CONVERT(datetime, EpEnd) <= GETDATE(), 0, IIF([TotVisits] < 5, 1, 0)))) = 0, 0, CONVERT(datetime, EpEnd) - GETDATE())
                  -- ^^^ change here
FROM [tb_Episode] AS [e]
LEFT JOIN [tb_Payer] AS [p]
     ON([e].[CustID] = [p].[company_id])
       AND ([e].[PayorType] = [p].[payor_type])
LEFT JOIN [tb_HHPPS] AS [h]
     ON [e].[HHPPS] = [h].[HHPPS]
WHERE 
    [e].[billed_flag] = '0';
```

By the way, the logic in your `SET` clause looks convoluted.  There is probably a way to simplify that as well.

**Edit:**

If, after making appropriate conversions for all datetime columns, you are still getting a conversion error, then I suggest that you have bad data somewhere in that column.  This sort of error is one of the reasons why you should not be storing date information as text.

Comment: @NikulPanchal Check my answer.  I think you only missed a call to `CONVERT` when referring to the `EpEnd` column, that is all.

Comment: Can you give me an example of some data stored in the `EpEnd` column?  Maybe it can't be converted to date.  By the way, don't store date information as text.  It will only lead to problems like this one.

Comment: I checked the data, its datatype is date, but there are data stored in datetime, like 2018-01-01 23:23:23

Comment: @NikulPanchal That data [has no problem being converted to datetime](http://rextester.com/WCS37366).  I suspect that you have some bad data, somewhere in that column.  I will update my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164686/discussion-between-nikul-panchal-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: Thanks for your hep, i have resolved the query issue

Answer (score 1):

I think your field `[e].[LUPADays]` is of `INT` type that's why you get the error when you try to set there your `DATETIME` value `EpEnd - GETDATE()`.
It should be `int`.

```
 UPDATE [e]
    SET 
        [e].[LUPADays] = CASE 
        WHEN [p].[payer_type] <> '1' 
            OR EpEnd <= DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()) 
            OR [TotVisits] >= 5 THEN 0
        ELSE EpEnd - DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE())
        END
    FROM [tb_Episode] AS [e]
    LEFT JOIN [tb_Payer] AS [p]
         ON([e].[CustID] = [p].[company_id])
           AND ([e].[PayorType] = [p].[payor_type])
    LEFT JOIN [tb_HHPPS] AS [h]
         ON [e].[HHPPS] = [h].[HHPPS]
    WHERE 
        [e].[billed_flag] = '0';
```

**UPD:**
It seems that your field EpEnd is neither `INT` nor `DATETIME` but maybe `VARCHAR`, so you should make some conversion here: `OR EpEnd <= DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE())` and here `EpEnd - DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE())`.

Comment: It is not working it gives me error 'Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int'

Answer (score 1):

I assume the column `[e].[LUPADays]` is an int. The result of your `IFF's` is either `0`, or `CONVERT(datetime,EpEnd) - GETDATE()`. This last expression results in a `datetime`, which sql server cannot implicitly convert to an int. What you are looking for is: `SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), EpEnd)` instead of subtracting datetimes.

Also, it helps if you don't add parentheses around everything, only use them where they are needed.